# I've successfully installed Cuda SDK and tested the compiler with an HelloWorld Then I've opened Nsight but Nsight can not opened

Tags: nsight

I've successfully installed Cuda SDK and tested the compiler with a HelloWorld. Then I've opened Nsight but Nsight can not opened.

Error that I get:

```
nsight
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Ignoring option MaxPermSize; support was removed in 8.0
CompileCommand: exclude java/lang/reflect/Array.newInstance
Gtk-Message: 16:52:26.477: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.eclipse.osgi.storage.FrameworkExtensionInstaller (file:/usr/local/cuda-10.2/libnsight/plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.10.1.v20140909-1633.jar) to method java.net.URLClassLoader.addURL(java.net.URL)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.eclipse.osgi.storage.FrameworkExtensionInstaller
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
Gtk-Message: 16:52:34.530: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and all the posts I found about installing various canberra-gtk-whatever packages didn't fix it.  What finally fixed it was to [install OpenJdk8 and then start nsight with that vm](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1048984/cuda-setup-and-installation/nsight-eclipse-won-t-launch-ubuntu-18-04/).  Apparently Nvidia requires that exact vm and didn't document it.  Typical poor documentation from Nvida.

I also have Oracle JDK 11 installed and only use OpenJdk8 to run insight.